# Слетела кодировка в Sublime Text и на сайте

Tags: html, кодировка, utf-8, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Слетела кодировка ,стоит utf-8,а щас просто вопросики.Открыл файл ,чтобы просто картинки в HTML поменять и слетела кодировка,я сохранил и она на сайте слетала ,как восстановить на utf-8?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `File -> Reopen with Encoding`, подбираете кодировку и сохраняете: `File -> Save with Encoding`.

Answer (score 0):

Я в таких случаях закрываю файл в ST и открываю в notepad++. Там работа с кодировками лучше.
Делаю преобразование в UTF-8 без BOM и красота